# Which informat statement can read the "yyyymmdd hh:mm:ssAM" date in sas

Tags: sas

I was trying to read the above data in sas dataset but couln't find any informat statement for this type.

Thank you.

Comment: datetime20. maybe?

Comment: Please add example data, so we can test our answer

Comment: The format is in this form "2012/09/06 12:00:00AM" and  is in a file with 10 of columns and around 10k rows.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in informat for this in SAS.  You also cannot create your own custom datetime informats that I am aware of.

This means you're going to have to do it the 'hard' way.

The below code extracts out the date part and the time part individually, and then combines them into a single datetime value.

You will notice to get from a date value and a time value to a datetime value, you can simply use the `dhms()` function, and place the time value into the 'seconds' parameter.

```
data _null_;

  have = '20160131 06:59:59PM';

  date_part = input(scan(have, 1), yymmdd8.);
  time_part = input(scan(have, 2), time10.);

  want = dhms(date_part,0,0,time_part);

  put date_part= date9. 
      time_part= timeampm.
      want= datetime22.;

run;
```

**Output:**

```
date_part=31JAN2016 time_part=6:59:59 PM want=31JAN2016:18:59:59
```

Comment: We can also use `scan()` to extract `time_part`...  `time_part = input(scan(have, 2),time10.);` (simpler than using `substrn()`)

Comment: SAS has a function for creating a datetime from the parts DHMS(date_part,0,0,time_part);

Comment: Thanks guys - updated.  Dom - I had a second space between the AM/PM originally hence the substr...

Comment: How do i do it when i have file loaded in the form of dataset and the name of the column is "stat_date"

Comment: @Fun.Rohit It seems to me that you might benefit from some introductory SAS tutorials.  I don't know how to make my answer any simpler than it already is sorry.